# How can I show the tags for each post in the result of my query - WP

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I have the following query:

```
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array( 
'post_type' => 'post',
'post','numberposts' => 9,
'post_status' => 'publish'

foreach($recent_posts as $post1) { $j++
```

and print the result in a html table.

```
echo $post1['post_title'];
echo $post1['post_content'];
```

but not how to display the tags associated with post

Answer (score 1):

If You know the **post_id** You can use:

`wp_get_post_tags( $post_id, $args )`

More here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_tags

Answer (score 0):

i can use

```
the_title();
get_the_content();
the_tags('Tags: ',','); etc
```

previously declared:

```
$temp_query = $wp_query; 
            $args = array(
                            'orderby'       => 'post_date',
                            'order'         => 'DESC',
                            'post_type'     => 'post',
                            'numberposts' => 9,
                            'post_status' => 'publish'
                        );

            query_posts( $args );

            if (have_posts()) 
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```